# How do I select a mat-radio-button in Angular Material with "selected" property of mat-radio-group?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have these lines of code

```
<mat-radio-group color="primary"
                       (change)="systemChange($event)">
        <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let system of systems"
                          [value]="system">{{system}}</mat-radio-button>
```

When I look at the page none of the buttons are selected by default and I want to make 1 of them selected. In [AngularMaterial docs](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/api#MatRadioButton) there is a

```
@Input()
 selected: MatRadioButton
```

and I cannot understand how to use it with `*ngFor` cycle or is there another way of solving this problem with `*ngFor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [value]="systems[0]" to your code:

```
<mat-radio-group color="primary" 
                 [value]="sys"
                 (change)="systemChange($event)">
```

with   sys = 'whatever' in your controller;

In this example the second radio is selected:

```
<mat-radio-group [value]="val" aria-label="Select an option">
    <mat-radio-button value="a">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="b">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="c">Option 3</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="d">Option 4</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

and

```
export class RadioOverviewExample {
  val = 'b';
}
```

Comment: If add [value]="systems[x]" 1 of the buttons completely breaks down and you can't select it

Comment: make sure that systems is initialized.  <mat-radio-group *ngIf="systems?.length" ...